# JSoup: get wikipedia page summary

Tags: html, css-selectors, jsoup

I used MediaWiki API to get a wikipedia page, after getting html content I tried using

```
p:not(h2 ~ p)
```

to get page summary paragraphs, it should be paragraphs before table of contents element, it gets the wanted part but has additional paragraphs, where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p:not(h2 ~ p)` gets *every single paragraph on the page* that doesn't have `h2` before it in the same parent. This includes nested paragraphs, paragraphs outside the main content altogether, etc, because none of those paragraphs share the same parent element as `h2` itself. You don't want those; you only want the paragraphs that appear just before `h2` elements within their parent element.

For that, you want to anchor the outer `p` selector to the parent element. The parent element you want is `.mw-parser-output`:

```
.mw-parser-output > p:not(h2 ~ p)
```

Comment: After testing I found that changing `#toc` to be `h2` will cover extracting summary from broader range of pages like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy (which would not be perfectly covered if we used `#toc`)

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Document doc = null;
    String url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nico_Ditch";
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8", url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Elements els = doc.select(".mw-parser-output > p:not(h2 ~ p)");
    System.out.println(els);
    // System.out.println(doc);
}
```

Run output:

```
<p class="mw-empty-elt"> </p>
<p><b>Nico Ditch</b> is a six-mile (9.7&nbsp;km) long linear <a href="/wiki/Earthworks_(archaeology)" title="Earthworks (archaeology)">earthwork</a> between <a href="/wiki/Ashton-under-Lyne" title="Ashton-under-Lyne">Ashton-under-Lyne</a> and <a href="/wiki/Stretford" title="Stretford">Stretford</a> in Greater Manchester, England. It was dug as a defensive fortification, or possibly a boundary marker, between the 5th and 11th centuries. </p>
<p>The ditch is still visible in short sections, such as a 330-yard (300&nbsp;m) stretch in <a href="/wiki/Denton,_Greater_Manchester" title="Denton, Greater Manchester">Denton</a> Golf Course. In the parts which survive, the ditch is 4–5 yards (3.7–4.6&nbsp;m) wide and up to 5 feet (1.5&nbsp;m) deep. Part of the earthwork is protected as a <a href="/wiki/Scheduled_Ancient_Monument" class="mw-redirect" title="Scheduled Ancient Monument">Scheduled Ancient Monument</a>. </p>
```

Process finished with exit code 0